# Why does this always return true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails query:

```
Model.exists?(where(:x => 1, :y => y, :z => z).first)
```

This is returning true. The only line in my database has x set to 0, not 1. Is there an explanation for this?

Ninja-edit: I checked and it seems none of the values matter, it always returns true. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL what was executed? You can find it in the debug log.

Comment: model.exists(:x =>1, ...) without where and without first. Also exists? is going to return a boolean not a row there should be no reason for first.

Comment: Thank you! Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. I am using where in other places and it works, which is why I was attempting to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is more along the lines of

```
Model.where(:x => 1, :y => y, :z => z).exists?
```

Comment: nate c's comment solved the problem for me but this might too. Unless there is an advantage in doing it your way, there's no point in me trying it.